# Set dropdown list selected value

Tags: c#, razor

I am using `Razor` engine but not using `MVC` framework for my project.
`DropDownList` is bound using following code.

```
var data= new List<SelectListItem>();
data.Add(new SelectListItem() {Text="abc", Value="1"});
data.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "def", Value = "2"});
var testDropdown= @Html.DropDownList("mydropdown",data);
```

I have checked answers which suggest use of `new SelectList()` or `DropdownListFor()` which I don't see in intellisense probably because it's not a `MVC` project but only rendering logic using cshtml pages.

I cannot convert to `ViewModel` or solution that involves using models.

Any easier way that I am missing to set selected value for `DropDownList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedListItem` has property `Selected` with setter. So you can just assign it like that

`data.Add(new SelectListItem() {Text="abc", Value="1", Selected=true});`

Answer (score 0):

try adding 'selected = true' when you create the desired item,

```
data.Add(new SelectListItem() {Text="abc", Value="1", Selected=true});
```

SelectListItem has a property Selected which takes a boolean type. So try 'true' or 1.

For reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem.selected(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: But there is no string property called `selected` in `SelectListItem` class